# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect double value: 'required'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, controller, laravel-8

I got the following error when I try to write $fillable in Model.
Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect double value: 'required' for column `db_productmanagementsystem`.`products`.`price` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `products` (`title`, `type`, `firstname`, `surname`, `price`, `papl`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

Model: Product.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'type', 'firstname', 'surname', 'price', 'papl'];
    //use HasFactory;
}
```

ProductController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products=product::all();
        return view('products', ['products'=>$products]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('createProduct');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'type' => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'papl' => 'required'
        ]);

        Product::create([
            'title' => 'required',
            'type' => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'papl' => 'required'
        ]);

        return redirect('/products');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Product $id)
    {
       
        return view('singleProduct', ['product'=>$id]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Product $id)
    {
        
        return view('editProduct', ['product'=>$id]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'type' => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'papl' => 'required'
        ]);

        $product=product::findOrFail($id);
        $product->title = request('title');
        $product->type = request('type');
        $product->firstname = request('firstname');
        $product->surname = request('surname');
        $product->price = request('price');
        $product->papl = request('papl');

        $product->save();
        return redirect('/products');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product=product::find($id)->delete();
        return redirect('/products');
    }
}
```

Database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op0TE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**You didn't provide the right value to your product model.**

Recheck your store method

```
Product::create([
        'title' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required', // here you passed a string. but this field type is double in the database schema
        'papl' => 'required'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get the Product values from the request:

```
 Product::create([
            'title' => $request->input( 'title'),
            'type' => $request->input('type'),
            'firstname' => $request->input('firstname'),
            'surname' => $request->input('surname'),
            'price' => $request->input('price'),
            'papl' => $request->input('papl')
        ]);
```